# JSON payload for Adaptive cards gets jumbled in body of http request

Tags: node.js, botframework, adaptive-cards

While trying to get the JSON from the body of a request, JSON.Parse jumbles the JSON elements, hence the webchat does not recognize it as an adaptive card.. Please help..

Node.JS Code:

```
var msgContent = {};
msgContent = getjson(function(resb){});
var msg = new builder.Message(session)
.addAttachment(msgContent);
session.endDialog(msg);

function getjson(callback){
request.JSON = true;
request.post("https://someapi.web.net",
function (error, response, body){
var resb = {};
resb = JSON.parse(body);
console.log(resb);
callback(resb);
});
};
```

Intended JSON:

```
{
"$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
"contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
"content": {
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "body": [{
        "type": "ColumnSet",
        "columns": [{
                "type": "Column",
                "size": 2,
                "items": [{
                        "type": "TextBlock",
                        "text": "Tell us about yourself...",
                        "weight": "bolder",
                        "size": "large"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "TextBlock",
                        "text": "We just need a few more details to get you booked for the trip of a lifetime!",
                        "isSubtle": true,
                        "wrap": true
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "TextBlock",
                        "text": "Don't worry, we'll never share or sell your information.",
                        "isSubtle": true,
                        "wrap": true,
                        "size": "small"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "TextBlock",
                        "text": "Your name",
                        "wrap": true
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "Input.Text",
                        "id": "myName",
                        "placeholder": "Last, First"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "TextBlock",
                        "text": "Your email",
                        "wrap": true
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "Input.Text",
                        "id": "myEmail",
                        "placeholder": "youremail@example.com",
                        "style": "email"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "TextBlock",
                        "text": "Phone Number"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "Input.Text",
                        "id": "myTel",
                        "placeholder": "xxx.xxx.xxxx",
                        "style": "tel"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "type": "Column",
                "size": 1,
                "items": [{
                    "type": "Image",
                    "url": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b2/Diver_Silhouette%2C_Great_Barrier_Reef.jpg",
                    "size": "auto"
                }]
            }
        ]
    }],
    "actions": [{
        "type": "Action.Submit",
        "title": "Submit"
    }]
}
```

Received JSON:

```
{'$schema': 'http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json',
content:
{ actions: [ [Object] ],
     body: [ [Object] ],
     type: 'AdaptiveCard' },
  contentType: 'application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive' }
```

Comment: Use `console.log(body)` instead of `console.log(resb)`. Node will default to only outputting 2 levels deep when logging an object, but `body` is the full JSON string.

Comment: @idbehold thank you so much for your response, but the issue is not with the [ [Object] ] part. The sequence of the elements in JSON gets jumbled. Not sure why the webchat does not recognize it if it gets jumbled. Only if the JSON is in the format as described in Intended JSON it populates the card.

Comment: That's… strange. In either case take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order

Comment: Can you share your bot code that reproduces the error?

Comment: @NilsW, thanks for your response. for some reason it started working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON objects are technically objects with *unordered* properties, so what you're seeing is a feature, not a bug.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/5525820/5199616 for detailed discussion.